# Proof of Simplification Rules

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to model a very simple communication protocol in Isabelle and the proofs are failing when trying to prove the simplification rules. I'm not sure what its trying to prove or what I need to add to help it along. I'm still learning Isabelle and getting used to the process; what am I missing here? Here is the code:

```
theory simple_prot
imports Main
begin

datatype Agent = Server | Friend nat
datatype Hi = ''HelloMessage''
datatype HiAck = ''HelloAck''
datatype Bye = ''ByeMessage''
datatype ByeAck = ''ByeAck''
datatype M = Hi | HiAck | Bye | ByeAck
datatype msg = packet Agent Agent M
datatype event = Says Agent Agent msg

inductive_set ns_public :: "event list set"
where
  Nil       : "[] ∈ ns_public"
  | Hi      : "⟦evm1 ∈ ns_public; A ≠ B; Says A B (packet A B Hi) ∉ used ns_public⟧
             ⟹ Says A B (packet A B Hi) # evm1 ∈ ns_public"

end
```

Here is the error:

```
Proving the simplification rules...

Proof failed.

1. ⋀x y xa evm1 A B used.
     x (?x27 x y xa evm1 A B used) ⟶ y (?x27 x y xa evm1 A B used) 
     ⟹ Says A B (packet A B Hi) ∈ used {x. y x}
     ⟶ Says A B (packet A B Hi) ∈ used {xa. x xa}

The error(s) above occurred for the goal statement:

mono  (λp x. x = [] ∨
         (∃evm1 A B used.
             x = Says A B (packet A B Hi) # evm1 ∧
             p evm1 ∧
             A ≠ B ∧ Says A B (packet A B Hi) ∉ used {x. p x}))`
```

Comment: The important part of the error message is the last paragraph, which tells you that Isabelle/HOL's inductive-package couldn't prove monotonicity of the inductive predicate you are trying to define. This can have two reasons, either your predicate is not monotone at all, or the built-in monotonicity rules that are employed by "inductive_set" (attribute "mono_set") need some manual extension. In your case, as long as `used` is not defined, I don't see how to provide the necessary `mono_set` rule.

Comment: Btw: what is the purpose of these `datatype T = ''...''`? This is not a legal datatype. Are just trying to define a constant `T` that is equivalent to the string `''...''`?

Comment: I want to make sure HelloMessage is only sent once and that order of the protocol is preserved. Could proving the monotonicity of the set imply this property? I thought having a `used` function might be required to check that the packet does not already exists in the set. Could this not be necessary? Thanks for the help